# How to import a Schema (XSD) which is in a jar file into another Schema(XSD)

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

I have some common types which are defined in an `xsd` file which is then later bundled as a jar file. I have this jar file in my classpath and I want to include this xsd into another xsd to use those types. How to refer the schema in a jar file? Also I want to create JAXB objects from the new schema is it possible. Also I want to use this new schema into my WSDL. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XJC tool offers a schema catalog mechanism for handling problematic imported/included schemas:

- https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#compiling-xml-schema-fixing-broken-references-in-schema

In your case you may need to interact with XJC programmatically.  Check out one of my answers to a previous question to see how this is done:

- [JAXB Ant Task Error: xjc2 [ERROR] null unknown location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478508/jaxb-ant-task-error-xjc2-error-null-unknown-location/3489799#3489799)