# Dynamic generation of classes using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I am trying to generate classes from xsd using `XJC` class of jaxb. however i am getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>   Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2:
>   E:\product.xsd

this is however the correct path where my xsd is present.

can anyone help me with this please.

my code is like :

```
File schemaFile = new File("E:\\product.xsd");
InputSource is;

is = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(schemaFile));
is.setSystemId(schemaFile.getAbsolutePath());
// Parse & build
sc.parseSchema(is);
```

Comment: Compare with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248099/jaxb-dynamically-generate-java-sources-without-xjc) approach

Comment: Try with `is.setSystemId("E:\\product.xsd");`

Answer (score 0):

The systemId is a URL, not a file.

Instead, use:

```
is.setSystemId(schemaFile.toURI().toString())
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561480/how-to-use-jaxb-apis-to-generate-classes-from-xsd/4664497#4664497) for a working example. Happy path-mangling!