# SchemaCompiler bind() returns null

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I' m writing a class to run xjc in java. my code goes as follows:

```
SchemaCompiler sc = XJC.createSchemaCompiler();
 URL url = new URL("file://E:\\JAXB\\books.xsd");
 sc.parseSchema(new InputSource(url.toExternalForm()));
 S2JJAXBModel model = sc.bind();
 JCodeModel cm = model.generateCode(null, null);
 cm.build(new FileCodeWriter(new File("E:\\JAXBTest")));
```

i get model as null when i run this.

Can anyone pls help me or provide any link where i can know abt this.

Comment: You already asked this question, why are you asking it again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561480/how-to-use-jaxb-apis-to-generate-classes-from-xsd

Comment: You only asked it 2 hours ago! Give people a chance. Asking duplicates will only get people irritated.

Comment: Google search yielded this question first.  Other question asks why NPE, and none of the answers hit on the solution as the answer to this one does.  Give the guy a break.

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the `SchemaCompiler` API for `bind()` method it says:

> bind() returns null if the compilation
>   fails.  The errors should have been
>   delivered to the  registered error
>   handler in such a case.

So, you need to register an error listener using `SchemaCompiler.setErrorListener()` with something like this:

```
sc.setErrorListener(new ErrorListener(){
  public void error(SAXParseException exception){
    exception.printStackTrace();
  }
});
```

And hopefully you will get more information on what is going wrong.

Comment: Nope nothing after adding this too

Comment: make sure you add it before parsing the schema and binding. If still nothing, try `exception.printStackTrace(System.err)`, maybe std-out is getting swallowed for some reason.

Comment: I must have missed this one -- I've answered the other question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561480/how-to-use-jaxb-apis-to-generate-classes-from-xsd/4664497#4664497 ). Really, simran, two hours is not really realistic...