# Create Java Classes via XSD File using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class, xsd

I am new to Java and Eclipse. What I now need to do, is creating Java classes by using a XSD file. I found some solutions online, but they all did not work for me. It is important, that there is **a code**, that does the job. **Clicking "generate"** is not the way, I want to realize the challenge.

JRE: jdk1.8.0_92

Libraries: jaxb-api.jar, jaxb-core.jar, jaxb-impl.jar, jaxb-jxc.jar, jaxb-xjc.jar

Comment: Why do you say "using Eclipse" in the title, and then say "Clicking generate is not the way", meaning that you don't want to use Eclipse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248099/dynamically-generate-java-sources-without-xjc Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks, Maciek! That's what I was looking for... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`xjc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/xjc.html) command that comes with Java.

> Compiles an XML schema file into fully annotated Java classes.

No need for any extra JAXB jar files.