# jaxb - how to map xsd files to URL to find them

Tags: jaxb, xjc

I have an xsd which has the typical import statements to import other xsd files but unfortunately, the references are hardcoded paths.  Is there a way in JAXB to override the location of those imports using a xbj file?

All of these xsds are delivered via another jar(inside the jar) so I would like to get the one off the classpath and when it imports the others try to configure it so it gets the others off the classpath.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a number of techniques you can use to address the issue:

**Catalogs**

You can use a catalog file to override schema location. Here's a couple of examples:

Use another schema depending on the namespace:

```
PUBLIC "http://example.org/A" "others/schema_a.xsd"
```

Use another schema depending on the schema location:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "https://example.org/a.xsd" "others/schema_a.xsd"
```

Allows you to use a local copy of a schema file.

See [this](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Fixing_broken_references_in_schema.html) and [this](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Usingcatalogs) guides.
Unfortunatelly, catalog support in XJC is not always working as expected and it's a bit hard to debug it.

**Resolving schemas from Maven artifacts**

If you're using Maven, you can use maven-jaxb2-plugin which can resolve schemas within Maven artifacts:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "https://example.org/a.xsd" "maven:org.example:a!/a.xsd"
```

In combination with catalogs, you can make JAXB use `a.xsd` inside `a-XXX.jar` instead of `https://example.org/a.xsd`.

See these sample projects:

- https://svn.java.net/svn/maven-jaxb2-plugin~svn/trunk/tests/catalog/
- https://svn.java.net/svn/maven-jaxb2-plugin~svn/trunk/tests/episodes/d/

Answer (score 1):

You could try interacting with XJC programmatically (see below) and plug-in your own EntityResolver to resolve the XML schemas:

```
import com.sun.codemodel.*;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.*;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.api.*;

SchemaCompiler sc = XJC.createSchemaCompiler();
sc.setEntityResolver(new YourEntityResolver());
sc.setErrorListener(new YourErrorListener());
sc.parseSchema(SYSTEM_ID, element);
S2JJAXBModel model = sc.bind();
```

Below is a link to a related answer I gave that some people have found useful:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3489799/383861

Comment: Programmatic usage? Even standard XJC supports catalogs, there's no need for such a deep impact.

Comment: @lexicore - My first though was an XML catalog (http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/10/jaxb-xjc-imported-schemas-and-xml.html).  The reason for suggesting the programattic approach is that the real schemas live in jars on the classpath, and there locations may not be configurable through an XML catalog.

Comment: Extracting JARs is also an option. :)